# Can you chain Anchor Pseudo-classes in CSS or SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am using SCSS and was wondering if there was a better way to write this...

```
.nav li a:hover, .nav li a:active, .nav li a:visited, .nav li a:focus
```

I would love if something like this was possible...

```
.nav li a:hover:active:visited:focus
```

Comment: How do you figure this would work, exactly?

Comment: @cimmanon: Easy, a visited link that is hovered, activated, and in focus. If you had something like `a:link:visited:hover:active:focus`, on the other hand...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### SCSS offers some assitance

You cannot chain pseudo-classes in CSS, but [in SCSS you can reference the parent selector with the `&`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) in nested syntax:

```
.nav li a {
    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:visited,
    &:focus {
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can, with the `&` character:

```
.nav li a {
    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:visited,
    &:focus {
    }
}
```

from [sass-lang.com](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector):

> & will be replaced with the parent selector as it appears in the CSS. This means that if you have a deeply nested rule, the parent selector will be fully resolved before the & is replaced.